# Creating time series data in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, time-series

I have data in two `numpy` arrays:

```
data = [0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 0.7]
time = [10,25, 27, 35, 42]
```

`data` corresponds to a value at the equivalent index of `time`

I want to create another array based a new `time` array that looks like this:

```
newtime = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
```

The new data array should look like this:

```
[0.1, 0.1, 0.4,0.6, 0.7]
```

Which corresponds to the value of `data` at each of the new times.  For example, at `10s`, the value was `0.1`, and at `20` seconds the value had not changed, so both should be `0.1`

The question is what's the easiest possible way to create the "new data" numpy from the  data array and time array in python? I would be happy to try other python libraries as well other than numpy.

Comment: maybe you can use dict

Answer (score 1):

Using searchsorted probably is one of the fastest ways

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 0.7])
time = np.array([10,25, 27, 35, 42])
newtime =np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])

newdata = data[ np.searchsorted(time, newtime, side="right") - 1 ]

print(newdata)
```

This prints out

```
[ 0.1  0.1  0.4  0.6  0.7]
```

Answer (score 0):

For this tasks you can use [RedBlackPy](https://intuitionengineeringteam.github.io/RedBlackPy/), it is supported for Python 3 on linux and macosx. RedBalckPy.Series class supports convenient functionality for time series, it keeps keys always sorted. You don't need to create new Series in your case, because interpolation is built into getitem operator(Series[key]). You have access at any key using interpolation(in your case floor). See the following code example:

```
import redblackpy as rb

# yours data and time
data = [0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 0.7]
time = [10,25, 27, 35, 42]

# create Series object with floor interpolation type 
series = rb.Series( index=time, values=data, dtype='float64',
                    interpolate='floor' )

# now you can access at any key using interpolation,
# it does not create new element, it just use neighbours (t_1 < key < t_2)
# in our case we set floor interpolation, so we get value for t_1
print(series[10]) # prints 0.1
print(series[20]) # prints 0.1
print(series[30]) # prints 0.4
print(series[40]) # prints 0.6
print(series[50]) # prints 0.7

# print Series, Series does not insert this keys
print(Series)
```

Last print gives the following:

```
Series object Untitled
10: 0.1
25: 0.3
27: 0.4
35: 0.6
42: 0.7
```

For more code examples, see article on [TowardsDataScience](https://towardsdatascience.com/redblackpy-fast-and-scalable-series-for-scientific-and-quantitative-research-in-python-cad49b5c6d3).